Bash 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
This very simplified version of my script
#!/usr/bin/env bash
example="$(bash -rs <<'BASH' -- 'This has been executed in restricted shell'
  echo "$1"
BASH
)"
echo "$example"

is executed without problems on a system with bash version 5.1.4. However, on another system with bash version 4.0.44, I get the error
line 2: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

If I change the script to
#!/usr/bin/env bash
example="$(bash -rs <<'BASH'
  echo 'This has been executed in restricted shell'
BASH
)"
echo "$example"

or
#!/usr/bin/env bash
bash -rs <<'BASH' -- 'This has been executed in restricted shell'
  echo "$1"
BASH

it also works on the system with bash version 4.
Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason?

This appears to be a bug in bash v4.0; I can reproduce it in bash v4.0.0, but it works for me in both v3.2.57 and v4.1.0. Moving the <<'BASH' to the end of the line (after the other arguments to bash -rs) solves it in my testing.

FWIW, handling heredocs correctly is perhaps the single nastiest part of parsing the shell language.

Here-docs as such should be pretty easy, really. (all you need to do is read and parse line-by-line.) But a line-based here-doc inside a command substitution that requires parsing the shell code inside to know where it ends? Witchcraft.

Well, it's a bug. Which one specifically, that is the question.
Could be this one, maybe:

j.  Fixed a bug that caused the shell to not recognize a here-document ending delimiter inside a command substitution.

But that's just a guess.
Old report on the bash bug mailing list: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2010-07/msg00052.html
